# Object type for an configuration object in java

Tags: java, configuration-files

I want to know how to make one object which contains all configuration settings the user filled into a configuration file. The configuration file is the only argument given to the program. I want to parse this configuration file once and check the key value pairs. This object must be known in all other objects.

Now I have a configuration object with only static methods, but first always the parseConfigurationFile method has to be called. I want this in some kind of constructor of this class. The static constructor cannot have arguments (which is logic because you don't create the object).

Is there a possibility to get the first argument given to the program in another object? Or do I have a wrong design for my configuration object? Or is this the best solution for my problem?

Maybe another solution is to remember the first method call of this object, when called for the first time, ask for the configuration file at the main class and parse the arguments then...

Which option will be the best solution for my problem?

Comment: what argument you want to pass, the config-file path? cant u have specific/fixed path to config file to read directly from static blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this is done by `.properties` files in java: [How to read Properties File in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/03/how-to-read-properties-file-in-java-xml.html).

Comment: I think this solution suites the best for my program, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you want an instance of a `ConfigurationManager`. The `ConfigurationManager` would instantiate as part of your program initialisation (perhaps in the `main()` method)

That instance would be passed to each component that needs it. When each component calls a method `manager.getConfiguration()`, that method *itself* checks whether the config is loaded, and loads it if required (i.e. is it the first initialisation?)

I wouldn't make anything static. I'd much rather have an instance of the class. That makes managing lifecycles etc. much easier. Note that the requirement of reading the config upon first call is tied up (encapsulated) within the manager and your clients (those consuming the manager) don't have to worry about this.

Note the above doesn't worry about how you're reading that config (using properties files, using Apache Commons Configuration etc.)